# Jquery toggle dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to create a jquery function that will toogle values for all selects in a table row. I've come up with this sollution

```
$(function () {
    $(".toogle").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("on") === true) {
            $(this).addClass("off");
            $(this).removeClass("on");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("on");
            $(this).removeClass("off");
        }

        $(this).each(function () {

            if ($(this).hasClass("on") === true) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('select').each(function () {
                    $(this).val("1");
                });
            } else {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('select').each(function () {
                    $(this).val("0");
                });
            }

        });
    });
});
```

You can see the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7BZNe/

but would like to know if it could be done in a better way.

Comment: If it's a 2-state field, you should use a checkbox.

Comment: I love the word toogle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of room for simplifying here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zt974/

```
$(".toogle").click(function () {
    $(this)
        .toggleClass("on off")
        .closest('tr')
        .find('select')
        .val($(this).hasClass("on") ? "1" : "0");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just what i was looking for, less code, and easier to maintain :)